Frequent alerts in Ubuntu 24 saying, 'Sorry the program "chrome" closed unexpectedly.'
I had installed Google Chrome and started using it, but after one day, I'm getting these warnings very frequently. I've tried uninstalling Google Chrome and VSCode, and still I'm getting these alerts.


When I deleted the Google Chrome crash file generated in /var/crash, it solved this issue.
$ sudo rm -rf /var/crash/_opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash 

